# Echoing data vertical and horizontal from joined table mySql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help. Maybe it's all about logical. So my case is:

I have mySql tables, they are:

record table

```
_______________________________________
Student ID  |  Question ID  |  Answer 
_______________________________________
     1      |       1       |    A
     2      |       1       |    C
     3      |       1       |    E
     1      |       2       |    D
     2      |       2       |    B
     3      |       2       |    A
   .......  |   ..........  |  ........
_______________________________________
```

and student table:

```
_________________________________
 Student ID   |    Student Name
_________________________________
       1      |      Ronaldo
       2      |       Messi
       3      |       Neymar
  ..........  |   .............
_________________________________
```

And I want to echoing them in my report page with table like this:

```
_________________________________________________
 Student    |         Question and Answer
            |____________________________________
            | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
_________________________________________________
 Ronaldo    | A | D | ...........................
 Messi      | C | B | ...........................
 Neymar     | E | A | ...........................
 ........   | ...................................
_________________________________________________
```

I use PHP so I repeat with foreach(){} function. But how to echoing data vertically and horizontally in once query?

Sorry for my bad php knowledge and logical. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I would say that this is something you absolutely want to handle in PHP and not in MySQL.

Comment: yes, maybe you're right...

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it (but by no means the only one) :

First fetch your users along with their answers :

```
SELECT 
    s.id AS student_id,
    s.name AS student_name,
    q.question_id,
    q.answer
FROM 
    students AS s
INNER JOIN
    questions AS q
ON
    s.id = q.student_id;
```

You should get rows like that :

```
array(
    'student_id' => '1',
    'student_name' => 'Ronaldo',
    'question_id' => 1,
    'answer' => 'A',
)
```

OR

```
array(
    'student_id' => '2',
    'student_name' => 'Messi',
    'question_id' => 1,
    'answer' => 'C',
),
```

You could then loop through them to reorganize them :

```
$data = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
    if(!isset($data[$row['student_id']])){
        $data[$row['student_id']] = array(
            'student_name' => $row['student_name'],
            'questions' => array(),
        );
    }

    $data[$row['student_id']]['questions'][] => array(
        'question_id' => $row['question_id'],
        'answer' => $row['answer'],
    );
}
```

Which will give you this array :

```
$data = array(
    '1' => array(
        'student_name' => 'Ronaldo',
        'questions' => array(
            array(
                'question_id' => 1,
                'answer' => 'A',
            ),
            array(
                'question_id' => 2,
                'answer' => 'D',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'student_name' => 'Messi',
        'questions' => array(
            array(
                'question_id' => 1,
                'answer' => 'C',
            ),
            array(
                'question_id' => 2,
                'answer' => 'B',
            ),
        ),
    ),  
);
```

Finally, loop through the last array to display data the way you want :

```
foreach($data as $student){
    echo $student['student_name'] . ' : ' ;

    foreach($student['questions'] as $question){
        echo 'Question ' . $question['question_id'] . ' : ' . $question['answer'] . "\n";
    }
}
```

You will need to do some adaptation to suit your need.